# Seemingly simple Odds question

Tags: probability

I have been out of academics for a while and have a quick question. I thought I could handle this one myself, but apparently I forgot more than I remembered.

Simple question.
Playing a random number betting game with friends.
Random Numbers range from 1-100.
Player bets an amount and rolls a number.

If 1-57 = House keeps the bet

If 58-98 = Player gets 2x their bet

If 99-100 = Player gets 3x their bet

How can I express this in a risk-reward ratio to help determine the houses estimated profitability of winning? I would the formula so I can tinker with the parameters.

Thanks in advance,

-Confused Gambler

--EDIIT: Thanks all, I think I got what I was after and able to tinker with the numbers as I was hoping to do. Sorry for using some incorrect terminology above, but I appreciate you working through it.

Comment: Risk is generally encoded in variance, reward in expected value. You can google how to calculate both.

Comment: Do you mean something other than the house edge?

Answer (score 0):

The player wins on average $(-1*57 2x41 + 3 +2)/100 = 34/100$ of his or her money. The variance is $((1.66)^2 * 98+ 2.66^2 2)/100=2.842,$ so the Sharpe ratio is $0.2$ (per bet).

Comment: for every $1 the gambler bet he'll get on average: 57*(-1) + 41*2+2*3 = 0.31 on each bet. No? Or did I miss something?

Comment: @adhg You are right, I misread the statement. Will fix.

Comment: great. Also, it means that on average he gets $0.31 for every bet; since he's in the positive territory - he's winning.

Comment: Follow-up: Can you explain the variance formula and how to interpret the Sharpe score? Thanks in advance.